# Pass a variable to a static google image map

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, reactjs

I have a variable where i store address on it.
I want to pass it to the google map static api:

like this

```js
adr = comp.adress; 
console.log(adr);// 28, rue Armand Carrel
```

```html
<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center={adr}&amp;size=600x300" alt="exemple" />
```

I don't get the value of adr what is wrong with the code ?

Spaces to Handle

```
 "addr": "\n                \n                28, rue Armand Carrel \n              ",
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing in yours is just reading the `{adr}` as part of your string.

Assuming the above is in `React`/`ES6`/`ES2015`.

You need to concatenate it to the string:

```
<img src={"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + adr + "&amp;size=600x300"} alt="exemple" />`
```

Or you can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
<img src={`https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=${adr}&amp;size=600x300`} alt="exemple" />`
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not related to reactjs.

You need to encode (using [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)) the address so it will be a valid url. Like this:

```js
//var address = '28, rue Armand Carrel';
var address = "\n                \n                28, rue Armand Carrel \n";
document.body.innerHTML = '<img src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=' + encodeURIComponent(address) + '&amp;size=600x300" alt="exemple" />';
```

If you want to reformat the address anyway:

```js
var address = "\n                \n                28, rue Armand Carrel \n";
console.log(address.replace(/\n/g, '').trim());
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, i'm getting the data from an a json, so it have like 15 spaces ...

So i figured out how to delete them, right now i need to delate the last space so i can display the map.

28,+rue+Armand+Carrel+ ( need to delete the last + )

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. You get the address in JSON or the image html? If you get the address, you just need to use the `encodeURIComponent()` and you will get a valid url.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/diK0xsg.png?1

I manged to replace al the "               "but i have one last "+" after Carrel i want to delete it to get the working adress.

Comment: Can you post here the text you get (from the image)? and I will show you how to handle it.

Comment: couldn't add the text stack delete all the spaces.

@i'll edit the original post

Comment: It looks like google can handle with the ugly string. Anyway I was updated my answer.

Comment: @Taieb is this answer your question?